# Line through price 1 if price 5 is set javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to achieve a strike/line through old price (P1) if there is a sale price (P5)

I think i'm pretty close, maybe somewhere along the else part that's stopping it from putting the line through old price if there isn't a sale price.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(jq('.spn_P5')){
   jq('.spn_P1').wrap("<strike>"); 
}
else{
if(jq('.spn_P5:empty')){
   jq('.spn_P1').unwrap("<strike>"); 
}
}
</script>
```

http://oi59.tinypic.com/359hl61.jpg

As you can see it is still applying the line through in the 2nd and 3rd product.

Could someone please assist.

Many Thanks.

Comment: you need to work on pair of (P1, P5)

Comment: I think we need to see the related HTML, this needs more detail, maybe throw up a jsFiddle link? You could probably figure it out yourself using fiddle, for that matter.

Comment: @BeNdErR please look at this http://jsfiddle.net/ many thanks.

Comment: @JeremyAnderson please look at this http://jsfiddle.net/ many thanks.

Comment: @user3303786: while the demo is useful, your question -including its relevant [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code- should be self-contained, in order that those that want to help can do so, by reading the question.

Comment: @user3303786 you have not linked the right jsfiddle..

Comment: @BeNdErR http://jsfiddle.net/ENfR6/ well this is embarrassing. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the returned length from `jq(".spn_P5:empty")`, this selector returns an object even if there is no content in the `.spn_P5` span. If the object has `length > 0` this means that an item matching the `:empty` selector was found

Assuming your HTML structure is something like this:

```
<div class="boot">
    <span class='spn_P1'>100€</span>
    <span class='spn_P2'></span>
    <span class='spn_P3'></span>
    <span class='spn_P4'></span>
    <span class='spn_P5'>200€</span>
</div>
```

You can do this:

```
if($(this).find(".spn_P5:empty").length == 0){ //--- check length here
   $(this).find('.spn_P1').css("text-decoration", "line-through");
}else{
   $(this).find('.spn_P1').css("text-decoration", "")
}
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/7q48R/

Comment: you have to adapt it to your needs/html structure

Comment: i tried replacing with my elements and it seems to place a line through even when there is no .P5

http://jsfiddle.net/ENfR6/

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion this is not a JavaScript job. You should add the `<strike>` tag directly in your template.

If you really like to do it with JavaScript, you have to do this based on ID's and not classes. Otherwise you always select all elements with the same class and this are always all prices in your case.

Comment: the reason why must use javascript is because this is a ecommerce site and we cannot manually alter the template files as it is shared with multiple clients.